# When would I see a nested "error" in this Angular error interceptor file?

Tags: javascript, angular, http-status-codes, angular-http-interceptors

I'm following a couple of Udemy tutorials online [link1](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/client/src/app/core/interceptors/error.interceptor.ts) [link2](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp/blob/master/client/src/app/_interceptors/error.interceptor.ts) that create an Angular error interceptor file on the client side.
I'm trying to understand how and when I would see a statement inside this file that looks like this with a nested error?

```js
if (error.status === 400) {
  if (error.error.errors) { // not sure why we would have a nested error inside error
    throw error.error;
  } else {
    this.alertService.danger(error.error.message);
  }
}
```

Here is the full file

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router, private alertService: AlertService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error) {
          if (error.status === 400) {
            if (error.error.errors) { // not sure why we would have a nested error?
              throw error.error;
            } else {
              this.alertService.danger(error.error.message);
            }
          }

          if (error.status === 401) {
            this.alertService.danger(error.error.message);
          }
          if (error.status === 404) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/not-found');
          }
          if (error.status === 500) {
            const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
              state: {
                error: error.error
              }
            };
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/server-error', navigationExtras);
          }
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

}
```

On the .Net server end I have controllers that return statements mostly like this:

```
return NotFound("Some message");
return BadRequest("Some message");
return Unauthorized("Some message");
return Ok();
```

Comment: Suspect that the response returned is something like: `{ error: { errors: [], message: "" } }`. Mind to share the tutorial link so we can look through it. Thanks.

Comment: It's a Udemy course - https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/DatingApp/blob/master/client/src/app/_interceptors/error.interceptor.ts The same instructor has this course as well. I think this is the one I used. - https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/client/src/app/core/interceptors/error.interceptor.ts

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the API code, so when API will return this response (as body content)

```
{ errors: [], message: "" }
```

but not *(which my comment was wrong)*:

```
{ error: { errors: [], message: "" } }
```

for error/exception cases. So the extra `error` is not from the API response.

Reference: [ExceptionMiddleware](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/API/Middleware/ExceptionMiddleware.cs)

---

I believe the `error` is a [`HttpErrorResponse`](https://v9.angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse). And it has the `error` attribute.

```js
class HttpErrorResponse extends HttpResponseBase implements Error {
  constructor(init: { error?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; })
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse'
  message: string
  error: any | null
  ok: false

  // inherited from common/http/HttpResponseBase
  constructor(init: { headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; }, defaultStatus: number = 200, defaultStatusText: string = 'OK')
  headers: HttpHeaders
  status: number
  statusText: string
  url: string | null
  ok: boolean
  type: HttpEventType.Response | HttpEventType.ResponseHeader
}
```

Hence, to get the ***error body***, you need:

```
error.error
```

Comment: Hi Yong. Thanks for the response. Can you explain what you mean by "so when API will only return this response"? Also how and when will I see this being used?

Comment: Hi, I re-correct my phase, mean the API to return error/exception response with body content of `{ errors: [], message: "" }`  but not `{ error: { errors: [], message: "" } }` . Sorry that my first explanation a bit confusing.

Comment: when will I see this body content? I want to test. How would I reproduce it?

Comment: You can try to submit a HttpPost with the body that aimed to fail the ModelState, from [Skinet3.1's ApplicationServiceExtensions](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/API/Extensions/ApplicationServiceExtensions.cs)

Comment: Or submit the request to [BuggyController](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/API/Controllers/BuggyController.cs). This will trigger the [ExceptionMiddleware](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/API/Middleware/ExceptionMiddleware.cs) and generate the response body with [APIException](https://github.com/TryCatchLearn/Skinet3.1/blob/master/API/Errors/ApiException.cs) type.